# Step number is not on top (introJs)

Tags: intro.js

I cannot seem to get the number of the step on top of the highlighted area as expected. I have version 0.5 of both js and css.

[image]

Any idea of what the problem is afshinm??

THanks a lot!

Comment: Well going on the information you gave us, it could be just about anything!

Comment: Sorry! If you click here you'll see the page live and be able to investigate the problem:
[link](http://test.preplounge.com/en/dashboard.php?keyid=92b933b597fe397f8fc95beeddf44d47&user_id=4784)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should add the relevant code here, or else create a JSfiddle!

Comment: on JSfiddle it works. Somehow in our website it does not. So if someone would be willing to help they would have to take a quick look into our code on the link in my comment above. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but unfortunately I've been unable to find a clean solution. In my case I believe it has something to do with using bootstrap 2. I narrowed the cause down to [stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FUnderstanding_z-index%2FThe_stacking_context) and I tried playing around with `opacity` to fix it, which worked, but created more bugs - you can find more on the opacity fix [here](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/).

If you don't want to read all of that text - go through the parents of the element you are highlighting with intro.js and add "opacity: 0.99" and you might be lucky to fix the problem *and* not get hit with other problems.

However, if that is out of the question, then the solution I went with was to reposition the numbers via the intro.js `onchange` callback like so:

```
intro.onchange(function(targetElement) {
   $(".introjs-helperNumberLayer").css("top", "-32px");
   $(".introjs-helperNumberLayer").css("left", "-1px");
});
```

Thanks to this, the numbers are farther away from the contents and nothing overlaps anymore.